# How can I generate a random number in a certain range? app keeps stopping

Tags: kotlin-android-extensions

android studio, kotlin

app keeps stopping after I try convert string to int. I need int to get random number.

New to kotlin so any help pls?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val goButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.goButton)
    val textViewResult = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewResult)
    val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTexts)
    val txt = editText.text.toString().toInt()


    goButton.setOnClickListener {
        val rand = java.util.Random().nextInt(txt)
        textViewResult.text=rand.toString()



    }
}
```

Comment: To generate int between a range, use the following Kotlin method

    fun randomInt(min:Int, max:Int):Int{
    val rand = Random()
    return rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min} . Leave the logs for why it is crashing or stopping, it gives more information.

Comment: can you give an example? User only input max value, min = 0

Comment: randomInt(0, yourMaxValue) will generate a random number between 0 and your max. However, since it is stopping working. I feel like there is something wrong with your layout and views.

Comment: <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="#A2A2A2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/goButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTexts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

Comment: app stopping work when I try user input convert into int. first I convert to string then int and then crash happen